# Why is this function still running even after the script is removed dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load a new script tag that replaces the jQuery content (within the `#clickmeDIV` DIV) with a new one dynamically but, once the second script tag is loaded into the `#clickmeDIV` DIV, the first script replaced is still running even when it's not part of the DOM. I confirmed that by checking the DOM with the chrome developer tools. Is it any way to completely erase the first script and then replace it with a new one dynamically (without reloading the page)?

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clickmeDIV">

  <script>
    $(document).on('click', '#clickmeDIV', function() {

      alert('Alert executed by the original script');
      $('#clickmeDIV').empty();

      $('#clickmeDIV').html('<script type="text/javascript">' +
        '$(document).on("click","#clickmeDIV", function(){' +
        'var foo  = function(){alert("Alert executed by the script inserted dynamically"); }; foo();' +
        '}); </s' + 'cript>');

    });
  </script>

</div>
```

Comment: Removing a script cannot undo what the executed code has done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attached a click event handler to the div with id clickmeDIV. You can remove it using

```
$(document).off('click', '#clickmeDIV');
```

Or

```
$('#clickmeDIV').off('click');
```

Read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 0):

Because it installs event handlers.

If you want to remove handlers, use jQuery's `off` function (versus `on` function).

According to [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$( "#clickmeDIV" ).off( "click" );
```

Would remove **all** the click handlers in `clickmeDIV` div.